# How to add value of form-field to a URL opens when the form has submitted

Tags: html, forms

I want to add values of text-box and a combo-box to a URL opens when the submit button pressed.

ex:- My first website is : www.example.com
     My second website is : www.example2.com

Then, below form is at second web-site. When it was submitted, submitter must  send to www.example.com/?sld='value-of-text-box'&tld='value-of-combo-box'

```
<FORM ID="form" action"">
<input type="text" id="domain" name="domain" value="" placeholder="domain-name">
<select name="tld" id="tld">
  <option value="com">com</option>
  <option value="net">net</option>
  <option value="org">org</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="button round">Go</button>
</FORM>
```

Anyone help me for this problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can try with method as "GET" in form tag.

```
<FORM ID="form" action="" method="get">
<input type="text" id="domain" name="name" value="" placeholder="domain-name">
<select name="Id" id="tld">
  <option value="com">com</option>
  <option value="net">net</option>
  <option value="org">org</option>
</select>
<button type="submit" class="button round">Go</button>
</FORM>
```

Comment: <FORM ID="form" action="" method="GET">

Comment: But it doesn't open example.com/?name='text-box value'&tld='combo-box value'  How it should be setup? with javascript

Comment: use modified code and sry i did not understand what you want with javascript

Comment: i modified question. Please tell me if you can't understand further.